# How to select a Pandas dataframe with an additional condition that won't change results?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

|  | currency | displaySymbol | figi | isin | mic | shareClassFIGI | symbol | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | USD | GDNRW | BBG014HVCMB9 | None | XNAS |  | GDNRW | Equity WRT |
| 1 | USD | DCHPF | BBG00D8RQQS7 | None | OOTC | BBG001SG1ZV8 | DCHPF | Common Stock |
| 2 | USD | RAYE | BBG0142KKR10 | None | ARCX | BBG0142KKSD5 | RAYE | ETP |
| 3 | USD | TRNIF | BBG01FZS3RZ4 | None | OOTC | BBG00M1B7Y30 | TRNIF | Closed-End Fund |
| 4 | USD | POTN | BBG000BXHT20 | None | OOTC | BBG001S7BTV1 | POTN | Common Stock |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 28030 | USD | AU | BBG000BCMDR8 | None | XNYS | BBG001S5NYW0 | AU | ADR |
| 28031 | USD | ECCC | BBG011DWM8Z1 | None | XNYS |  | ECCC | PUBLIC |
| 28032 | USD | BZLFF | BBG000C0V028 | None | OOTC | BBG001S61C32 | BZLFF | Common Stock |
| 28033 | USD | DRIV | BBG00KLHY7D7 | None | XNAS | BBG00KLHY836 | DRIV | ETP |
| 28034 | USD | AHAHF | BBG00CSP14G0 | None | OOTC | BBG001S9YD10 | AHAHF | Common Stock |

I want to select some rows by multiple conditions like this:

```py
dirty_data = df[
    (df['description'] == '')       # condition 1
    | (df['description'] == 'Test') # condition 2
    | (df['shareClassFIGI'] == '')  # condition 3
    | ...
    ]
```

This code arrangment lets me be able to comment out some conditions to review easily:

```py
dirty_data = df[
    (df['description'] == '')
    # | (df['description'] == 'Test')
    # | (df['shareClassFIGI'] == '')
    | ...
    ]
```

but commenting out the first condition raises an error:

```py
dirty_data = df[
    # (df['description'] == '')
    | (df['description'] == 'Test')  # Invalid syntax! There is a `|` before the first condition
    | (df['shareClassFIGI'] == '')
    | ...
    ]
```

I add `False` before all conditions, and it solves my problem:

```py
dirty_data = df[
    False
    | (df['description'] == '')     # Now I can comment out this line without errors
    | (df['description'] == 'Test')
    | (df['shareClassFIGI'] == '')
    | ...
    ]
```

But sometimes I want to comment out all contidions to show and check the original dataframe, but it raises `KeyError`:

```py
dirty_data = df[
    False                           # KeyError: False
    # | (df['description'] == '')
    # | (df['description'] == 'Test')
    # | (df['shareClassFIGI'] == '')
    # | ...
    ]
```

`dirty_data = df[False]` is invalid syntax.

Is there an expression to replace `False` that could fit my need?

---

**Edit:**

I think my original logic code was wrong. It's not easy to return a **truthy** if there is no condition, make it **falsy** if there is any condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an idea by creating a helper function for that:

```py
def hp(df, empty_selection, boolean_indexing):
    if type(boolean_indexing) == pd.core.series.Series:
        return boolean_indexing
    if type(boolean_indexing) == bool:
        return [empty_selection] * len(df)
    raise Exception('boolean_indexing type error')

# Show all data (without any condition)
dirty_data = df[ hp(df, True, False
    # | (df['description'] == '')       # condition 1
    # | (df['description'] == 'Test') # condition 2
    # | (df['shareClassFIGI'] == '')  # condition 3
    # | ...
    )]

# Show the results for condition 3
dirty_data = df[ hp(df, True, False
    # | (df['description'] == '')       # condition 1
    # | (df['description'] == 'Test') # condition 2
    | (df['shareClassFIGI'] == '')  # condition 3
    # | ...
    )]
```

To simply the code and improve the readibility, the function can be added to the class DataFrame:

```py
def search(df, boolean_indexing):
    if type(boolean_indexing) == pd.core.series.Series:
        return df[boolean_indexing]
    if type(boolean_indexing) == bool:
        return df
    raise Exception('boolean_indexing type error')


# Show all data (without any condition)
r = search(df, False
    # | (df['description'] == '')       # condition 1
    # | (df['description'] == 'Test') # condition 2
    # | (df['shareClassFIGI'] == '')  # condition 3
    )

# Show the results for condition 3
r = search(df, False
    # | (df['description'] == '')       # condition 1
    # | (df['description'] == 'Test') # condition 2
    | (df['shareClassFIGI'] == '')  # condition 3
    )


# You can also bind the function to the class DataFrame
pd.core.frame.DataFrame.search = search

# Show the results for condition 3
r = df.search(False
    # | (df['description'] == '')       # condition 1
    # | (df['description'] == 'Test') # condition 2
    | (df['shareClassFIGI'] == '')  # condition 3
    )
```

Now the code arrangement is like a search bar. The default is showing all data, and showing the results when there is any condition input. You can switch on/off any condition. You can try any condition by just add a line to the code without writing boilerplate code (creating a Jupyter Notebook cell, write `df[...]` again), and leave the condition as a search history by just commenting it out. In this manner, you can focus on the conditions and the results to understand the data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's nice if it suits your usecase :) - I would just suggest [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) for type checking instead of `type == <something>`.

I personally prefer defining "nicely" named masks stored in variables instead, because I can easily reuse them anywhere in the code, but this seems to be a nice little solution for what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, comments should not be any part of code, so I'd avoid doing what you're asking for as much as possible. If you must slice the dataframe with different condition list, why not compose a function like this:

```
def slice_with_cond(df: pd.DataFrame, conditions: List[pd.Series]=None) -> pd.DataFrame:
    if not conditions:
        return df

    # or use `np.logical_or.reduce` as in cs95's answer
    agg_conditions = False
    for cond in conditions:
        agg_conditions = agg_conditions | cond
        
    return df[agg_conditions]
```

Then you can slice:

```
# return df
slice_with_cond(df)

# return a slice
slice_with_cond(df, [cond1])
```

Comment: upvote for the "IMHO, comments should not be any part of code" but it is an interesting ask nonetheless

Comment: Thanks, but it is just in Jupyter Notebook for data research (playground). I won't deploy this code.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @Quang Hoang, here is one option how to achieve what you want:

- define a boolean mask with `True` of length `len(df.index)`, which will therefore always select all data
- combine the selection with other conditions you want to apply via `&` instead of `|`

This should ensure, that whenever you delete (or comment out) all conditions apart from the first one, the whole dataframe will get selected.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'currency': ['USD', 'USD', 'USD', 'USD', 'USD'],
    'displaySymbol': ['GDNRW', 'DCHPF', 'RAYE', 'TRNIF', 'POTN'],
    'figi': ['BBG014HVCMB9', 'BBG00D8RQQS7', 'BBG0142KKR10', 'BBG01FZS3RZ4', 'BBG000BXHT20'],
    'isin': ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'],
    'mic': ['XNAS', 'AHA', 'ARCX', 'OOTC', 'OOTC'],
    'shareClassFIGI': ['', 'BBG001SG1ZV8', 'BBG0142KKSD5', 'BBG00M1B7Y30', 'BBG001S7BTV1'],
    'symbol': ['GDNRW', 'DCHPF', 'RAYE', 'TRNIF', 'POTN'],
    'type': ['Equity WRT', 'Common Stock', 'ETP', 'Closed-End Fund', 'Common Stock']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

mask_true = [True] * len(df.index)
```

---

Selecting data with some conditions defined:

```
df[
    (mask_true) # make sure to return all data
    & (         # define remaining conditions
        (df['type'] == 'ETP')
        | (df['mic'] == 'OOTC')
    )
    
]
```

Output

```
    currency    displaySymbol   figi    isin    mic shareClassFIGI  symbol  type
2   USD RAYE    BBG0142KKR10    None    ARCX    BBG0142KKSD5    RAYE    ETP
3   USD TRNIF   BBG01FZS3RZ4    None    OOTC    BBG00M1B7Y30    TRNIF   Closed-End Fund
4   USD POTN    BBG000BXHT20    None    OOTC    BBG001S7BTV1    POTN    Common Stock
```

---

Selecting data with all conditions removed but the default boolean mask

```
df[
    (mask_true) # make sure to return all data
    # & (         # define remaining conditions
    #     (df['type'] == 'ETP')
    #     | (df['mic'] == 'OOTC')
    # )
]
```

Output

```
currency    displaySymbol   figi    isin    mic shareClassFIGI  symbol  type
0   USD GDNRW   BBG014HVCMB9    None    XNAS        GDNRW   Equity WRT
1   USD DCHPF   BBG00D8RQQS7    None    AHA BBG001SG1ZV8    DCHPF   Common Stock
2   USD RAYE    BBG0142KKR10    None    ARCX    BBG0142KKSD5    RAYE    ETP
3   USD TRNIF   BBG01FZS3RZ4    None    OOTC    BBG00M1B7Y30    TRNIF   Closed-End Fund
4   USD POTN    BBG000BXHT20    None    OOTC    BBG001S7BTV1    POTN    Common Stock
```

---

---

Hopefully this is what you have been looking for.

Comment: How to just comment out the first condition without error?

Comment: You can again create a `mask_false` and use it as a first input for the set of the custom conditions, like so:
```df[(mask_true) & ((mask_false) | (df['type'] == 'ETP') | (df['mic'] == 'OOTC'))]```

Just note that when you will want to remove all custom conditions, you will need to comment out the whole custom-condition block (everything after the `&`)